# Reading image data using a .txt file containing file names

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, python-imaging-library

I am using Tensorflow to make a CNN that can classify images. I have a `images.txt` file that contains a list of the `.jpg` files along with their corresponding labels, with the following format:

```
image1.jpg,4
image2.jpg,3
image3.jpg,2
```

I have written a function that opens the `.txt` file and iteratively read the data of the images using Pillow:

```
data = []
labels = []

def preprocess():
    with open('images.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            // Did some string processing to get path of the image

            img = Image.open(path)
            arr = np.array(img.getdata(), dtype=np.int8)
            data.append(arr)
```

I am not sure of the natural speed of this procedure, but it seems pretty slow. I need to read around 5000 images (i.e. `images.txt` contains around 5000 lines), and it's taking me around 60 seconds to finish running this function.

Could someone perhaps shed some light on this and let me know what to do to improve its performance? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The optimized way of doing this is to use Tensorflow for doing everything.

There's a straightforward way to do this:

```
# load csv content
csv_path = tf.train.string_input_producer(['images.txt'])
textReader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_content = textReader.read(csv_path)
im_name, label = tf.decode_csv(csv_content, record_defaults=[[""], [0]])

# load images
im_content = tf.read_file(im_name)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(im_content, channels=3)
# preprocess your input image (scale, subtract mean, resize, ...)

# make batches
bs = 32
im_batch, lb_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=bs)
```

In this way you're using Tensorflow to read the CSV, the images and the labels and create batches of size 32.

You can just use `im_batch` and `lb_batch` as input and and targets to your network.

Comment: Thanks, but when I am checking the accuracy of my predictions, this line  ```train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})```produces an error: ```TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
``` How do I solve this?

Comment: You don't have to use it as values for placeholder. They're already part of the graph, hence you don't have to feed anything. Read this guide for a better understanding: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data

Answer (score 1):

## Use new Dataset API(released as part of TF 1.4 version) to Speed up entire process

**Step for reading from CSV Files:**

1) Read the CSV file name 
2) Create TextLineDataset by providing the CSV file name
3) Create the Parse function for decoding and do any preprocessing work in input data
4) Create batching, repeat(no of epoch) and shuffling using dataset created in previous steps
5) Create the Iterator to fetch required inputs as a batch(i.e. mini-batch)

Eg code:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
def input_model_function():
    csv_filename =['images.txt']
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(csv_filename)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(20)# you can use any number of batching
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    sess = tf.Session()
    batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
return {'x':batch_images}, batch_labels

def _parse_function(line):
    image, labels= tf.decode_csv(line,record_defaults=[[""], [0]])
    # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
    image = imread(image)# give full path name of image
return image, labels
```

Finally input batched Dataset into Model(created using any Pre-Made Estimator or Custom Estimator API)